# Why my cmd program always be paused automatically?

Tags: java, windows, cmd

When I use cmd(start->run->cmd) to run java ant build or something else program. Normally The command will run the program continuously until all tasks has to be done. on the process of runing, the cmd consle will output specific some log continuously.

But My promblem is that the cmd always be paused automatically after few minutes. it will be restart if I phsyically enter any keystroke to awaken it up. it's really boring I need keep watch on the cmd.exe on all time.

Any way or configration to solve this, or any tools instead of windows cmd.exe to archieve the same function?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a couple of possible explanations:

1. Your Java application is pausing when it tries to read something from `System.in`.
2. You are actually running a batch file that uses the "pause" command at some point.

(FWIW: the `cmd.exe` program also implements pausing / continuing using CTRL-S / CTRL-Q, but (AFAIK) that requires you to physically enter the control characters from the keyboard ... and that's not happening.)

Comment: Thank your reply, but it both are not for your thinking of possible explanations. it's very strange that I did't physically enter any order to let command do this. I am using window 7 as you know window 7 has more safety control.